# Grafana: display a static line on the bar graph

Tags: graph, grafana

I would like to display a line on the bar graph in Grafana. The line should be display depends on the dashboard constant value. I managed to display this line as a threshold, however I'm wondering if it is possible to display it from dashboard variable. My main datasource is MySQL database.

The line should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can't do exactly what you want](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/922#issuecomment-1058424892). However, you can have some sort of dynamic thresholds if you set your threshold from the result of a query.

You can either use the [Config from query results](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/reference-transformation-functions/#config-from-query-results) transformation or the [Rows to fields](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/reference-transformation-functions/#rows-to-fields) one.